# Probability that the sum of visible faces is $72$?

Tags: probability, number-theory

$5$ dice are stacked one over the other to make a **column**.

$4$ faces of each of the first $4$ dice are visible while $5$ faces of the topmost die is visible.

What is the probability that the sum of the visible faces is $72$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** In real dice, the sum of any two opposite faces is $7$. So this is a trick question, much simpler than it looks.

Comment: Didnt get your answer.

Comment: It's not truly a trick, but think about what Andre said. Opposite faces of a die always add up to 7. Now envision the column in your mind...

Comment: I guess what Andre means is that 14*5+2=72

Comment: The sum of the "side faces" is $(5)(2)(7)$. So the sum is $72$ precisely if the top face of the top die shows a $2$. The probability of this is $\frac{1}{6}$.

Comment: Oh wow its so pathetically easy !!! (please guys do help improve my reputation)